# Running scalatest and Maven with two scala libraries - one for Maven, the other for Scala Eclipse plugin

Tags: scala, maven

The scala Eclipse plugin requires scala 2.10.0 to run :

[image]

To run the 'test' goal on Maven I require the dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest_2.9.0-1</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.M5</version>
</dependency>
```

As part of this dependency 'scala-library-2.9.0-1.jar' is also added to build path :

[image]

This causes an error to be displayed on problems tab in Eclipse :

> More than one scala library found in the build path. At least one has
>   an incompatible version. Please update the project build path so it
>   contains only compatible scala libraries.

How can I fix this error ? I need both scala libraries, one is for the scala eclipse plugin and the other for the scalatest maven plugin. I don't want to just delete the error from the problems tab.

Answer (score 2):

> The scala Eclipse plugin requires scala 2.10.0 to run :

It has versions for both 2.10 and 2.9, install the one for 2.9.2 (and use ScalaTest for version 2.9.2 as well). Or use a version of ScalaTest for 2.10, but it seems you'll need to build and install it locally, there isn't one for 2.10.0-RC2 listed at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest.

Comment: @user470184 Under "For Scala 2.9.x", see also http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html